# UML for local variables

Tags: java, uml

If I have 2 java classes, one class's method  contains method variable that is a reference to the second class (not instance variable). How do I link these classes in UML diagram?
I am giving an example for better clearance of question:

```
class A{
     methodA(B b){
      <do something>
} 
}

class B{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dependency, kind of weak relationship. In this case it is establish only while the method execution and is typically merely indicated with a generic dependency:

[image]

Stronger kinds of relationships, like association or composition usually suggest member variables.

Comment: Just curious why the arrow is not full like the association. I only use the dash arrow for dependencies without using the instance like passing as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

If any class contains the reference of any other class (other than instance variable) then this relationship is know as **composition Relationship**. It can be depicted in UML using a class relationship.
The black diamond represents composition in UML class diagram. The arrowhead on the other end of the relationship denotes that the relationship is navigable in only one direction.

Comment: This is not true. Composition indicates the strongest relationship possible, of a Whole-Part kind. In case of composition, a "Whole" (here A) controls the life-time of the "Part" (here B), which is here obviously not the case. In this case we have a weak and short-term dependency between A and B. See my answer for an example.

Comment: **Aggregation:** One object A has or owns another object B, and/or B is part of A. 

**Composition:** In addition to an aggregration relationship, the lifetimes of the objects might be identical, or nearly.
For Reference check [Ref1.](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~cs3443/uml/uml.html) and [Ref2](http://aviadezra.blogspot.in/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html)

Comment: exactly, that just confirms my comment, in this case there is no such relationship. :) And look at the second diagram in Ref1 - just the situation from the question and the solution I suggested. Thanks. :)